# Shehecheyanu on new website

Tags: blessing, internet, shehecheyanu, simchah-joy-happiness

If one launches a [new website](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning), can he recite Shehecheyanu? Or perhaps Hatov Ve-Hametiv, if [others](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users) derive benefit from it?

Comment: Questions like this always remind me of Fiddler on the Roof's blessing on Mottel's new sewing machine.

Comment: A sewing machine, at least, has tangible existence in the real world.

Comment: YAY we got full commitment

Comment: @R'Dave, re tangible: Whaddaya call bits? Spiritual? ` ;-) ` Incidentally, I'll quit calling people R' when we migrate to the new site, as "@Dave" will then be flagged for R'Dave's attention (while @R'Dave won't).

Comment: @HRH"G R'msh210, not everything physical is tangible. When was the last time you touched a byte?

Comment: BTW, this is a SERIOUS question! :)

Comment: How would someone launching a new site know whether others will benefit? OTOH, if it's something like m.y, which is merely migrating to a new platform and not a wholly new site, then, perhaps, even if a _b'racha_ is made on a new site, it's not made in this case.

Answer (score 3):

How about simply, Besha'ah Tovah!

Comment: Seems appropriate. After all, the site is still beta.

Answer (score 2):

Following the lead of the new fruit for the second day of Rosh Hashana (because we're not sure if we should say that bracha for that day), shouldn't you find some other reason to say Shehecheyanu in close proximity to the questionable event?

Comment: That makes sense as a practical answer if the _halacha_ is unclear about whether to say the _b'racha_. But (a) this Web site is not good for practical _halacha_ (one should contact an authority instead) and (b) maybe (and answers may help clarify this) _halacha is_ clear about whether to say the _b'racha_.

Comment: I just saw this answer again and wondered if, ironically, it had been my first answer here.  Alas no; it was my second.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question about the website being a physical entity that one finishes or acquires is an interesting one - can it get a brocha? Like a new shirt of a new tallis?

I think yes. Any website still has existence on a server somewhere - even if its data is stored energy on a laser disk - it still exists as a physical recording on the physical plane.

Now I think the more interesting question - is that do we need to stand next to the designated server in order to make the brocha - or is looking at the computer screen enough? And by extension can I make a brocha on a picture of a new tallis that someone bought for me and took a photo of?

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to Mi Yodeya! None of us know you, so your assertions held on your authority are not worth very much to anyone else. Please [edit] in a source for your understanding if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

hatov vehametiv I'm certain that you don't, the only case is when someone brings a second bottle of wine during a meal you have with other people.

as for sheehianu, it would make sense if you are happy, I guess comparable to printing a book.
but the website is not done, it is a work in progress and also there's no takana of beracha on this case.

it doesn't mean that you shouldn't thank hashem for it, praying or making a seuda.

Comment: Not really correct about "hatov vehameitiv." Any benefit that would deserve a "shehecheyanu" gets "hatov vehameitiv" if it benefits others as well (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 222:1; see also 223:1).